# Assembly in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I want to understand something regarding assembly in .NET.
I have one console apps and one class library (strongly named) in VS2022.
The console apps makes a reference to the class library.
I have deployed the class library dll to GAC with a version (2.0.0.0)
yet I kept the reference in console app to the class library with version 1.0.0.0.
I was expecting that when I run the console app from VS, it should fail because I thought,
with strongly named assembly, the system looks into GAC and if the expected assembly has a
different version from what is in GAC, it should throw an exception. But it is not the case.
But when I copy all the assemblies (.EXE and dell) to a different folder and run the .EXE file, it fails and throws FileLoadException.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQbir.png)

My question is to understand why it does not fail when run from VS?
Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Your app is .NET Framework? GAC is [obsolete in .NET Core and later versions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/global-assembly-cache-apis-obsolete) The exception might be thrown simply because DLL is not found, not because you have the wrong version in GAC.

Comment: Also, the behavior in VS2022 for .NET Framework apps might be different for Debug and Release modes. There are not enough details in your question to really know what's going on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Strong named assemblies are only for a unique identity - as the GAC would need. The .NET Framework runtime uses strong names (and the GAC). The .NET (aka .NET Core) runtime ignores strong names (and the GAC). Are your console app and class library .NET Framework or .NET? Are both projects in one solution?

Comment: Does the executable require other files?  Check the bin folder of the project to see what files are in the folder.  When you copy a exe to another folder you must also copy other dependency files.  The error says cannot load file or assembly.  You may be missing a required dependency.

Comment: The console app and the class library are .NET Framework. BTW I copied the executable and it's dependency to another folder and I run the executable it fails  since the assembly version l in GAC is different from the expected one. But when I run from VS it doesn't fail yet GAC has a different version from what is in VS. I am wondering if when I run from VS it checks the GAC. The assembly in GAC is strongly named.

Comment: MSBuild ensures the .exe has a local copy of the .dll, version 1.0.0.0 because that's the one you referenced.  The GAC cannot supply version 1.0.0.0.  So the CLR keeps looking and finds the local copy.